# SQL - Joining a table table twice on seperate id's without replacing the original id

Tags: mysql

Ive got a table of trips with a 'to' location and a 'from' location.  These locations are in 3 letter acronyms. I want to add information to this table in my query by adding information about the to location based and from location.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    imoova._relocation_deals A, 
    imoova._airport_codes_lookup B, 
    imoova._vehicle_types C 
WHERE 
    A.active = 1
AND A.location_from = B.code 
AND B.country = :country 
AND A.vehicle_type_id = C.id
```

Basically I want to add:`A.location_to = B.code` to the query.  I have looked at joins and unions however to my knowledge they won't work to append the tables twice to the result. Ideally I'd like to be able to produce a result similar to this.

```
to  | to(city)  | to(country) | from | from(city) | from(country)|
------------------------------------------------------------------
BNE | Brisbane  | AUS         | SYD  | Sydney     | AUS          |
```

I have no idea if this is possible because it would be essentially creating new columns in the result but if it is it would save me a lot of time! Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can join a table multiple times, but each join needs a unique alias so the DB can differentiate WHICH of the "clone" tables you're talking about.

```
SELECT ..., a.id, b.id
FROM MainTable
JOIN sometable AS a ON ...
JOIN sometable AS b ON ...
```

Comment: Thank you, Alias was what I was looking for :)